# JPQL- Fetching Parent entities along with matched child entities based on some criteria on child entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have two JPA Entities having OneToMany relationships.

**Department**:

```
@Entity
public class Department {
@Id private int id;
private String name;
@OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "department", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Employee> employees;
// ...
}
```

**Employee**:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
@Id private int id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="DEPT_ID")
private Department department;
// ...
}
```

Now I want to fetch all Department where Employee name starts with 'A' and the Collection returned should only contains those 
Employees which are matching the criteria.

For Example, If Department A has 5 employees whose names are A, B, C, D, E and Department B has 3 employees 
whose names are A, AA, Z The query should result in :

List size = 2.

```
Department A
            id=1
            name='A'
            Set<Employee> size 1 with name 'A'

Department B
            id=2
            name='B'
            Set<Employee> size 2 with name 'A' and 'AA'
```

How can I achieve this using JPQL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: What if I want to fetch Department with no Employees?

Comment: `SELECT d FROM Department d INNER JOIN FETCH d.employees e WHERE e ...`

Comment: Thanks @crizzis . It worked like a charm.

Comment: @crizzis. What if I want to fetch Department with no Employees?